# Reactjs REST API not printing to screen

Tags: reactjs, rest, axios

Using the Reactjs npm environment to develop a REST API client.  The below does not produce any errors nor does it print to screen.  Want to print out JSON at some point, but anything that looks correct is fine for now.

```
import Axios from 'axios';
import React from 'react';
class FirstC extends React.Component {
  render() {

const axios = require('axios')
axios.post('http://192.168.100.55/rest/seltec/auth/loginuser/', {

Username: 'tictac',
    Password: '123smile',
    DeviceUuid: '123232-5872-3809-b2e6-5108bdc2dd',
    DeviceModel: 'PN-20221301223',
    DeviceSerialNumber: 'SN-54324118',
    FcmToken: 'dFEEp5MST36vd_lzkbPK8n:APA91bEIGZo-7nEhfkbFwCcmRGNyFy9YfcyRgaCcSKblLpJ2sy8SBO8_lHXgElH5YAAnnB7NSCc66ac3R1oQ2ITQ0Jvlra9mznIGxzfR-jwLDRUmUelE8nM-2Z3xQn3OR1my1fJ04gR4'

  })
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  })

    return  <div>
lll
 
           </div>;
      }
}
export default FirstC;
```

The App.js file is below:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import FirstC from './components/FirstC.js';
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <p>
          </p>
          <FirstC />
        </header>
        <FirstC />
</div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

We use Postman to verify the RESTful clients, which shows it outputting the correct JSON.

Comment: Your axios post return an error, add this after your .then 
<< .catch(function (err) {console.log(err);}  >>
I think your token need to be at the third axios's params

Comment: const axios = require('axios'), put it on the top like  import axios from 'axios'

Comment: @ Aurelio LIMA FERREIRA Thanks for your input.  Put this "const axios = require('axios') "  right under import   And did this:   .then .catch(function (err) {console.log(err);}(function (response) {
  //.then(function (response) {
   // console.log(response);
  })       But no luck.